# canvasJS chart not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

I'm trying to `render` multi line chart using `canvasJS` but it's not working as expected.

Here is my drawChart function

```
function drawChart(obj, placeholder){
var dataPoints = [];
var maxPrice = [];
var minPrice = [];
//console.info(obj);
for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dataPoints.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
    minPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].minPrice});
    maxPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].maxPrice});
}
console.log(dataPoints);
console.log(maxPrice);
console.log(minPrice);
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
    animationEnabled: true,
    //theme: "theme1",
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: placeholder
    },
    data: [
        {
            type: "spline",  //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Average Price", 
            dataPoints: dataPoints    //this line I tried to change
        },
        {
            type: "spline",  
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Min Price", 
            dataPoints: minPrice
        },
        {
            type: "spline",  
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Max Price", 
            dataPoints: maxPrice
        }
    ],
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: function (e) {
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
        }
        chart.render();
        }
    }
});

chart.render();
```

}

`var dataPoints, maxPrice, minPrice` has same layout/data.

look here.[image]

it's displaying chart like this, reset of two lines `minPrice and maxPrice` are vanished.

[image]

**PS** If I change `dataPoints: dataPoints` to `dataPoints: min/maxPrice` it doesn't work either that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I'm posting so it could be helpful for someone else.

I suspected that if you're trying to render chart dynamically, then for `y-axis` you need to use `Math` function to make it work.

So I changed these

```
dataPoints.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
minPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].minPrice});
maxPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:obj[i].maxPrice});
```

**To**

```
dataPoints.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].avgPrice * 1000) / 1000});
minPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].minPrice * 1000) / 1000});
maxPrice.push({label:obj[i].year+"-"+obj[i].month+"-"+obj[i].day,y:Math.round(obj[i].maxPrice * 1000) / 1000});
```

and now it's working fine, may be this could be a bug in `canvasjs` or may be I was messing somewhere.

Look here[image]